# Where to get apache poi port for .net

Tags: .net, apache, dll, apache-poi

I would like to know if there is a website where I could download the Apache POI ported for .net?

I already found this link in the web
http://www.apache.org/~avik/dist/poi-2.5.1-dev-20040708.dll

I also found a repository of poi.net from novel but it is quite old (2004)
http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Poi.Net

But the version of apache poi now is 3.6, I was wondering if there is a latest version out there? Does the apache foundation support such porting? I already tried to search the apache website too with no avail.

As for using Microsoft library, the excel interopt is not that good for concurrent processing like a web backend. If I use the DocumentFormat.OpenXML library, I have a limitation of creating office 2007 document only.

If there is no library out there? is there a JAR to .NET assembly(.dll) converter tool out there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out the answer. You can get the latest apache poi version then convert the jar into dll on your own using IKVM.NET. After that, add the assembly of the POI dll to your .net application plus the IKVM.NET core and JVM dll. And you can finally use the Apache POI in your  .NET project.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is a partial port of POI to .NET, named [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).

(Found it on [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c))

Comment: As of 2016, it looks like NPOI is about a year or more behind POI.