# POI DLL in .net

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to get apache poi port for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680546/where-to-get-apache-poi-port-for-net)

Where can i download the latest POI DLL in .NET?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using NPOI? http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

See [Where to get apache poi port for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680546/where-to-get-apache-poi-port-for-net)

Comment: Is it possible to convert jar to dll?

Comment: Yes.  Read the answers to the linked question.